# I'm trying to add a hair system but every time i try the hairs go off along the axis and at weird angles any help?

Tags: particles, hair, system

[zoomed out shot of a simple plane with a hair particle system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpIs7.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect you have a randomize setting enabled in your particle system.  Could you at least include a screenshot showing the particle system settings?  Although it would be better if you included your blend file.  (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: @MartyFouts i think i added it there thanks for the help. Couldn't find any setting where i randomized anything

Comment: @MartyFouts damn now i cant even open the file without blender crashing I've no idea what's going on lol

Comment: i opened your blend file, selected plane, then pressed tab -> edit mode -> tab again -> object mode -> and i got: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuVxH.png ...maybe you should try it on another computer?

Comment: which version of blender are you using.  I'm not having any problems with your blend file ?with 2.92.

Comment: @MartyFouts alright it must be my computer then because I cant even download and open my own blend file. I'll try restarting it thanks for your help